# How to getdata from webpage table

Tags: python

On the website https://www.shanghairanking.com/rankings/arwu/2020
the URL doesn't change when I hit "next".  Any ideas on how to scrape the tables on the next pages.  Using bs4 in Python, I am able to only scrape the table on the first page.

What I did so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

html_text = requests.get('https://www.shanghairanking.com/rankings/arwu/2020').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')  

data = soup.find('table', class_= "rk-table").text.replace(' ','')
print(data)
```

Comment: Try (the package) selenium.. It allows you to programmatically launch a web browser, go to the website and click on "View Full List". Then you may use beautiful soup to gather the information that you need.

Comment: I tried selenium also didnt help in finding URL for new page